# Rails testing for pair uniqueness in database association table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord

Each User can vote for a Post, modelled by an association: Each User `has_many :voting, through: :active_vote_relationships`. They should only be allowed to vote once, so I've got `unique: true` in the schema:

```
add_index "voterelationships", ["voter_id", "voted_id"], name: "index_voterelationships_on_voter_id_and_voted_id", unique: true, using: :btree
```

I'm trying to test this by getting a User to vote for a post he has already voted for:

```
test "shouldn't be able to vote again for a post already voted for" do
  assert_no_difference '@user.postvoting.count' do
    xhr :post, voterelationships_path(voter_callsign: @user.callsign, voted_id: @post_1.id)
  end
end
```

I was expecting the test to pass. Instead I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_voterelationships_on_voter_id_and_voted_id"
```

It seems the uniqueness requirement is correctly preventing duplicate pairs in the table, but why does that cause a testing error rather than a pass? I thought the second vote attempt would simply be rejected by the database. How do I get the test to pass?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. You should use `assert_raises` to assert that an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` exception will be raised.

Example:

```
assert_raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique do
  xhr :post, voterelationships_path(voter_callsign: @user.callsign, voted_id: @post_1.id)
end
```